# How to divide the column values in to ranges

Tags: r

I would like to  know how to divide the column values in to three different ranges based on scores.

Here's the following data I have

```
Name    V1.1    V1.2    V2.1    V2.2    V3.1    V3.2
John    French  86      Math    78      English 56
Sam     Math    97      French  86      English 79
Viru    English 93      Math    44      French  34
```

If I consider three ranges. First rangewith 0-60, Second rangewith 61-90 and third range with 91-100.
I would like to the subject name across all the skills.

Expected result would be

```
Name   Level1    Level2      Level3
 John  English   Math,French  Null
 Sam   Null      French,Eng   Math
 Viru Math,Fren  Null        English
```

Comment: You could turn those ranges into factors, which would then be easily displayed however you like.

Comment: @Badger  can you elaborate it please?

Comment: so what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another option using `splitstackshape` and nested `ifelse`

```
library(splitstackshape)
library(tidyr)    

# prepare data to convert in long format
data$subjects = do.call(paste, c(data[,grep("\\.1", colnames(data))], sep = ','))
data$marks    = do.call(paste, c(data[,grep("\\.2", colnames(data))], sep = ','))
data = data[,-grep("V", colnames(data))]

# use cSplit to convert wide to long
out = cSplit(setDT(data), sep = ",", c("subjects", "marks"), "long")

# nested ifelse to assign level based on the score range
out[, level := ifelse(marks <= 60, "level1", 
               ifelse(marks <= 90, "level2", "level3"))]

req = out[, toString(subjects), by= c("Name","level")]
```

this will give

```
#> req
#   Name  level              V1
#1: John level2    French, Math
#2: John level1         English
#3:  Sam level3            Math
#4:  Sam level2 French, English
#5: Viru level3         English
#6: Viru level1    Math, French
```

you can reshape either using `dcast` or `spread` from `tidyr`

```
spread(req, level, V1)

#   Name       level1          level2  level3
#1: John      English    French, Math      NA
#2:  Sam           NA French, English    Math
#3: Viru Math, French              NA English
```

**data**

```
data = structure(list(Name = structure(1:3, .Label = c("John", "Sam", 
"Viru"), class = "factor"), V1.1 = structure(c(2L, 3L, 1L), .Label = c("English", 
"French", "Math"), class = "factor"), V1.2 = c(86L, 97L, 93L), 
    V2.1 = structure(c(2L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("French", "Math"
    ), class = "factor"), V2.2 = c(78L, 86L, 44L), V3.1 = structure(c(1L, 
    1L, 2L), .Label = c("English", "French"), class = "factor"), 
    V3.2 = c(56L, 79L, 34L)), .Names = c("Name", "V1.1", "V1.2", 
"V2.1", "V2.2", "V3.1", "V3.2"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))
```

Comment: I tried increasing the levels from 3 to 5. In that case, I am unable to see the level1 range. Following is the code I tried.                                    ifelse(marks <= 20, "level1", 
                      ifelse(marks <= 40, "level2", 
                          ifelse(marks <= 80, "level3",  
ifelse(marks <= 90, "level4",  "level5"))))]

Comment: @Ram that is because marks for non of the students is less than 20, if you have an instance of <20 level1 will appear.

Comment: @Veeredra Gadekar Tried doing that as well, Even then ended up with 4 levels, without displaying level1

Comment: @Ram try changing john's french marks  to 20 in your sample data and then use the neseted ifelse. It should be something like this `out[, level := ifelse(marks <= 20, "level1",  ifelse(marks <= 40, "level2", ifelse(marks <= 80, "level3", ifelse(marks <= 90, "level4", "level5"))))]`
and let me know..

Comment: Couldn't see any change.

Comment: for me it works fine.. you are working on the sample data in the question or your original dataset??

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105929/discussion-between-veerendra-gadekar-and-ram).

Answer (score 4):

First you need to convert the data to long form, one row per observation (where an observation is a single score.  You need to do a melt, but it is complicated because your wide form consists of not only observations but observation classes.  One way to do it is to use `melt.data.table` twice, but you may be more comfortable with `dplyr`, which has more accessible syntax.

```
# first you need to convert to long form

library("data.table")
setDT(df)

lhs <- melt.data.table(df, id = "Name",  measure = patterns("\\.2"), 
                       variable.name = "obs", value.name = "score")
lhs[, obs := gsub("(V\\d+)\\.\\d+","\\1",obs)]
lhs
rhs <- melt.data.table(df, id = "Name", measure = patterns("V\\d\\.1"), 
                       variable.name = "obs", value.name = "subject")

rhs[, obs := gsub("(V\\d+)\\.\\d+","\\1",obs)]
rhs

df2 <- merge(lhs, rhs, by = c("Name","obs"))

#    Name obs score1 subject1
# 1: John  V1     86   French
# 2: John  V2     78     Math
# 3: John  V3     56  English
# 4:  Sam  V1     97     Math
# 5:  Sam  V2     86   French
# 6:  Sam  V3     79  English
# 7: Viru  V1     93  English
# 8: Viru  V2     44     Math
# 9: Viru  V3     34   French
```

Then you need to use `cut` or some other function to create the three levels based on score1.

Then you should group by these levels and apply concatenation to the subjects, such as `paste(..., collapse = ",")`.

Then you need to use `cast` or `spread` to return it to wide form.

Do give it some effort, and edit your question with what you've tried, and try to come up with a more specific question, not just "please do this for me".

Answer (score 0):

Not very intuitive, but leads to the requested output. Requires the package **sjmisc**!

```
library(sjmisc)
mydat <- data.frame(Name = c("John", "Sam", "Viru"),
                    V1.1 = c("French", "Math", "English"),
                    V1.2 = c(86, 97, 93),
                    V2.1 = c("Math", "French", "Math"),
                    V2.2 = c(78, 86, 44),
                    V3.1 = c("English", "English", "French"),
                    V3.2 = c(56, 79, 34))

# recode into groups
rec(mydat[, c(3,5,7)]) <- "min:60=1; 61:90=2; 91:max=3"

# convert to long format
newdf <- to_long(mydat, "no_use", 
    c("subject", "score"),
    c("V1.1", "V2.1", "V3.1"),
    c("V1.2", "V2.2", "V3.2")) %>% 
  select(-no_use) %>% 
  arrange(Name, score)

# at this point we are at a similar stage as described in the 
# other answers, so we have our data in a long format 

newdf

fdf <- list()

# iterate all unique names
for (i in unique(newdf$Name)) {
  dummy <- c()
  # iterare all three scores
  for (s in 1:3) {
    # find subjects related to the score
    dat <- newdf$subject[newdf$Name == i & newdf$score == s]  
    if (length(dat) == 0) dat <- ""
    dat <- paste0(dat, collapse = ",")
    dummy <- c(dummy, dat)
  }
  # add character vector with sorted subjects to list
  fdf[[length(fdf) + 1]] <- dummy
}
# list to data frame
finaldf <- as.data.frame(t(as.data.frame(fdf)))
finaldf <- cbind(unique(newdf$Name), finaldf)
# proper row/col names
colnames(finaldf) <- c("Names", "Level1", "Level2", "Level3")
rownames(finaldf) <- 1:nrow(finaldf)

finaldf
```